# Amazon S3 Register streamWrapper so long

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have launched a php application with AWS Beanstalk. Everything is working but i have some slowness with S3.

I'm using this code :

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
$s3 = S3Client::factory();
$s3->registerStreamWrapper();
```

I'm using SDK V2. When i put above code, my page take few seconds more to be fully loaded.

Could you help me ?

Thanks and regards,

Thomas.